# Creating xml file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

in my asp.net page i have register page. i want to create a xml file with parent and child nodes of xml  like :

```
 <Personal Details>
    <First Name> ... </First Name>
    <Last Name> ... </Last Name>
 </Personal Details>
 <Bank Details>
    <Bank Name> ... </Bank Name>
    <Account No> ... </Account NO>
 <Bank Details>
```

and store the xml file in datbase widht parent and child nodes.

Comment: Can I ask why you're putting credential in XML? You'll be far better off putting them in some sort of SQL.

Comment: Usually one stores the data fields (last, first, bank, account) in the database... ?

Comment: AHHHHHHH!!!! I just notice the "Bank" field in your XML. If you're putting banking details in XML, can you send me the name of the site? That way I can a) not use your site, and b) gather up some nice banking details for my next trip to Honolulu.

Comment: no it is just my example not my application  @rockinthesixstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of way to generate XML. you can try something like

```
        XElement element =
            new XElement("SomeRoot",
                new XElement("PersonalDetails", 
                    new XElement("FirstName","FirstNameValue"), 
                    new XElement("LastName"),"LastNameValue"),
                new XElement("BankDetails", 
                    new XElement("BankName","BankNameValue"), 
                    new XElement("AccountNo","AccountNoValue")));
```

and

```
element.ToString()
```

will give you xml string with a root element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XmlWriter class.
Here you can find a sample code: http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend using XML for membership (as I stated in my comment, SQL is better, and can still be free).

That being said, to semi answer your question I'd recommend using an [XML Membership Provider](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20xml%20membership%20provider&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) to deal with your authentication. It's pre-built, easy to implement, and you're not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use .net but I do from time to time use asp.  When I do I'll sometime use ASP XMLMaker for what you're looking to do.  There's an ASP.NET XMLMaker too, take a look, it may help in what you need.  [enter link description here](http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetxmlmaker/)